# Taking a lot of time to build gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I'm doing a project in my office in `Android Studio`, it was working fine there.
But when I open the same project in my personal laptop in `Android Studio` it's taking a lot of time to build `gradle`.
Please, does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Did you check what is wrong with gradle on your computer? Try executing ./gradlew tasks --info to see what is going on.

Comment: might be because of lot of use of libraries..

Answer (score 1):

I have also face same problem, actually your personal laptop not compatible to run android studio, in the documentation of android they mentioned that 4 GB RAM is sufficient but my personal experience said that RAM should be 8 GB, its also depend on your operating system in MAC os android studios running smoothly then in Linux its also give good performance but in Windows its creating a problem, i think you need to upgrade your RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to the file:

org.gradle.daemon=true
From now on Gradle will use a daemon to build, whether you are using Gradle from command line or building in Android Studio. You could also place the gradle.properties file to the root directory of your project and commit it to your SCM system. But you would have to do this, for every project (if you want to use the daemon in every project).

Note: If you don’t build anything with Gradle for some time (currently 3 hours), it will stop the daemon, so that you will experience a long start-up time at the next build.

Note: Performance improvements are one of the great tasks in the Gradle roadmap for 2014 (and reaching into 2015). So I hope, we’ll see the general performance increasing within these years.

Note: This does only affect console builds. Android Studio always uses a Gradle daemon (and depending on your settings some other optimizations).

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason!! If Android Studio has a proxy server setting and can't reach the server then it takes a long time to build, probably its trying to reach the proxy server and waiting for a timeout. When I removed the proxy server setting its working fine.

On Windows File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System settings > HTTP Proxy